# plain text in XML in scala

Tags: xml, scala

If I make a variable like this:

```
val x = <a>H<b>i</b>!</a>
```

how does Scala represent the text objects? If I were making the system, you'd have some List of elements that looks something like this:

```
L(0): TextElement = TextElement("h")
L(1): BElement    = BElement(TextElement("i"))
L(2): TextElement = TextElement("!")
```

But I don't see anything about `text elements` in any documentation (or really very much about how this works at all.)

How is it implemented in Scala?

Comment: what do you mean by "represent the text objects"?  There is a scala.xml.Text class which does what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is `xml.Text` :

```
scala> x.child.map(_.getClass).foreach(println)
class scala.xml.Text
class scala.xml.Elem
class scala.xml.Text
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/xml/package.html